# The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get a session to work and I feel like I'm probably missing something really obvious. I have a master page in an ASP project and in it I have this code for the logged-in event of a log-in object on the master page:

```
protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Session.Add("Username", Login1.UserName);
    }
```

So the session should contain the username used in the Log-in object to log in

In the master page's contents I'm just trying a simple reference by making it show the username used to log in:

```
Welcome <%Response.Write(Session("Username"))%>
```

But "session" is underlined in red, saying "The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context". I've been trying to figure out what I'm missing but so far what I've tried hasn't done anything.

Any Advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: Did you google the error message? Always do that before asking and then tell us what you tried. I suspect the issue is that your class does not inherit from Page or try `HttpContext.Current.Session`

Comment: You should also use <%= %> instead of <% %>, like this: Welcome <%= Session["Username"] %>

Comment: Also, you'll need to use brackets: `Session["Username"]`

Answer (score 4):

I think it's maybe a problem of a namespace

Do you can try with :

```
<%Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Session("Username"))%>
```

Comment: ? are you try this solution guy ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Session["UserAuthentication"] = username;
```

use [] not ().

Answer (score 1):

use like this: `session["authentication"]`

Answer (score 0):

Add a using statement.

```
using System.Web;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["abc"]
```

Comment: First of all, format your code as code, not as plain text. Second of all, while this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.